# Landscape mode malfunction

Tags: lyx, landscape

I upgraded to Ubuntu zesty a few days ago and had to reinstall lyx and some packages from texlive.  Everything functions as before, except, all of a sudden, pdf output in landscape mode is broken.  The text is disposed correctly, but the pdf page size is still 8.5x11 portrait.  So you get a pdf file (viewed with evince as usual) with much of the text cut off and white space where the page should have already ended.  I do not know how to troubleshoot this problem.  I've already purged and completely reinstalled lyx.  There are no errors in the logs.  I've tried adding the usepackage geometry, landscape.  This document worked just fine before upgrading to zesty.

[image: landscape pdf broken]

UPDATE:
Minimum example:

• Memoir Class
• Fonts via Xetex
• Landscape Layout
• User Defined Margins (.5in. for all - .25in footer)

If compiled using Xelatex it is broken:

[image: With Xelatex]

If compiled using LuaLatex it works:

[image: With LuaLatex]

Comment: This is your fourth question, please provide the minimal required code in order to show your problem. A (LaTeX) software update shouldn't have this effect (in my opinion it is unlikely). Have you tried **different pdf viewers** to make sura that it is a LaTeX problem and not a pdf viewer problem?

Comment: A `.lyx` file is a text file. You can create a mwe with LyX, open it with any editor and then edit your post and add it.